# Partitioning 2 Hard drives to run Linux only

Tags: partitioning, ssd

Hello friends I am a new Linux user and have decided to go with the Ubuntu distribution. What I would like to know is how to correctly partition my hard drives.

I have a 16 GB SSD and 500 GB HDD running on Thinkpad w540. I plan to use the following partition scheme:

On the 16 GB SSD 300 MB for boot efi to load the boot-loader and the remaining as root partition. On the HDD drive the first partition will be `/usr` of 50 GB and the remaining will be for `/home`.

I have 16 GB of ram in the laptop so I don't much care for having swap, also I do not use heavy applications/software neither do I do gaming. My primary use of this laptop is learn Linux and computer networking. The reason I want the `/usr` on the HDD is that I will be installing much software and hence will quickly run out of space on the SSD.

If I am mistaken and horribly wrong, please guide me in the right direction. I really like using Linux and would not want to go back to the moronic operating system called Windows and quite frankly I am not rich enough to buy a MAC. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, at first glance your scheme makes perfect sense. I wish all the newbies were like you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea seems good, but I manage partitions in a different way.
I find partitions somewhat too rigid, and I always try to create a minimal amount of them.

Another thing to consider is that SSD are really faster than HDD, to the point I consider that I can't work anymore with a HDD based computer.

**My recommendation**

1. Do the whole setup on the SSD, with one partition for `EFI` and one for `/`.
2. Mount the HDD in `/mnt/hdd`
3. Use your computer for some time, and when some directory grow too big, move it to the hdd.

It's possible to use symbolic links (`ln -s`) to link data to somewhere else, but I use [bind mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/130000).

**Example**

Example: My music is in `/home/pim/music` which is on the SSD, but I want to move those files to the HDD.

- Reboot to single user mode
- Create a directory on the HDD : `mkdir -p /mnt/hdd/bind/home/pim`
- Make sure the user `pim` can access and write to `/mnt/bind/home/pim`
- move the data : `mv /home/pim/music /mnt/bind/home/pim`
- create the future mount point `mkdir -p /home/pim/music`, once more permissions should match the user.
- And now the real trick : **bind mount** the directory, by adding this line to `/etc/fstab` : `/mnt/hdd/bind/home/pim/music /home/pim/music none bind`
- try to mount it with `mount -a`
- reboot and enjoy.

**Downsides**

- `locate` will index the files twice, this can be fixed by adding `/mnt/hdd/bind` to `PRUNEPATH` in `/etc/updatedb.conf`
- While doing backup, care must be taken to not  copy those data twice. `cp` and `rsync` both have `-x` flag for not crossing filesystem boundaries.

**About /home on another partition (or bind mount)**
You are talking about a laptop, but for a remote server, I always take
care of having a user with a home directory on the `/` partition, so I can
login even if the drive containing `/home` fails.

Answer (score 0):

As you state correctly, 16 GiB isn't much if you install lots of applications. I would actually combine the two SSDs into a single logical volume with mdadm or LVM, if you don't mind the additional complexity of it. 32 GiB should be enough for most of your needs. If you don't mind the increased risk of data loss on those partitions (since it's just system files and applications) you can have the logical volume span the drives in “striped” mode (RAID0) for some additional performance.

Third-party applications should be installed in `/usr/local` or `/opt`  anyway and you could put those on separate file systems on the HDD.